Opening 'link in bio' in default mobile browser without prompt
When tapping a link in bio on an Instagram profile, by default the link opens in the Instagram browser. However, I need the link to be opened in the default mobile browser (Chrome, Safari etc) without any change in settings by the user. I have found 3 types of solutions online for this but none of them are proper solutions:
Solution 1 - Fake downloading a file on the page so the Instagram browser redirects the visitor to the native mobile browser. Link
Solution 2 - Using a URL scheme such as googlechrome://domain to redirect the URL request to the native mobile browser. Link
Solution 3 - Using JS to open a new tab or new window (does not work).
Most of these solutions do not work in iOS and even when they do, Instagram prompts the user saying "You are leaving the app. Do you want to continue?"
Recently, I found a service which has achieved this without any Instagram prompt. The service is https://getallmylinks.com and on their website they call it Deeplink Technology. Here is an example link: https://getallmylinks.com/david
If this link is added to an Instagram bio, tapping the link takes the visitor straight to the native mobile browser without any prompt.
I have inspected the bio page to find any specific JS or HTML code that may enable this but couldn't find out what it is. Could someone please help me achieve this the way getallmylinks.com has?
